# Transpose records from 2 "one to many" tables into one record

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions

Basically, I would like to get a recordset similar to this:

```
CustomerID, CustomerName, OrderNumbers
1           John Smith    112, 113, 114, 115
2           James Smith   116, 117, 118
```

Currently I am using an Sql Server UDF to concatenate order #s.

Are there more efficient solutions ?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Keep your two tables. It will cause you headaches instead later on.

Like that you're violating the first normal form.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: @brunch875 I don't think he wants to physically combine the two tables, I think he just wants a query to display like above, probably for reporting reasons.

Comment: Yes, just display for reporting reasons.  I am now thinking about combining recordsets on the application level as opposed to the DB.

Comment: @David I would try doing something similar as the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 0):

1) [There are allot of solutions](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

2) Example (SQL2005+):

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE (
    CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT @Customer VALUES (1, 'Microsoft');
INSERT @Customer VALUES (2, 'Macrosoft');
INSERT @Customer VALUES (3, 'Appl3');

DECLARE @Order TABLE (
    OrderID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL -- FK
);
INSERT @Order VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT @Order VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT @Order VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT @Order VALUES (4, 1);
INSERT @Order VALUES (5, 2);

SELECT  c.CustomerID, c.Name, oa.OrderNumbers
FROM    @Customer AS c
/*CROSS or */OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), o.OrderID) FROM @Order AS o
        WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        -- ORDER BY o.OrderID -- Uncomment of order nums must be sorted
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS OrderNumbers
) oa;
```

Output:

```
CustomerID  Name      OrderNumbers
----------- --------- ------------
1           Microsoft 1,4
2           Macrosoft 2,3,5
3           Appl3     NULL
```